# Tomcat manager authentication

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a build server that builds application. Then I'm going to deploy WAR file to production server with Tomcat running. I'd like to use Tomcat's manager functionality for this.

Question: what types of authentication are available when calling app manager? I cannot use login/password for some reasons. I'd like to use something like private/public key pair.

Comment: it would help with the suggestions if the reasons of not using login/pass would be told

Comment: Generally speaking: it's hard to transmit password to build server: there is no secure channel.

Comment: what if you just use private/public keypair to connect through ssh, scp the files and deploy with autodeploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, Tomcat's manager webapp can be configured to use any of the authentication mechanisms that are supported in any web application: FORM, BASIC, DIGEST, or CLIENT-CERT.

CLIENT-CERT is the only one of the above options that does not use username/password, so that seems to be your only option. Obviously, you'll need SSL configured for Tomcat (which should not be a problem, as using insecure HTTP for your manager app is quite foolish), and you'll need to configure a trust store containing a cert in your cert chain above the client certificates you are issuing.

If you want something more elaborate, you are going to have to build it yourself.